# Как передать данные в таблицу MySQL c помощью Java

Tags: java, mysql

Я новичек в MySQL. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить вопрос с передачей данных в таблицу MySQL.
Данные передаются GET-запросом.
Определен вот такой сервлет, который получает в строке значение и передает на страницу:

```
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    String temp = request.getParameter("temp");
    String hum = request.getParameter("hum");
    try {
        writer.println("<h2>Temperature: " + temp + "; Humidity: " + hum + "</h2>");
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }
```

Создается таблица (это будет отдельный сервлет? или новый класс?):

```
    // create Table
    String sqlCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE parameters (Temperature INT , Humidity INT )";
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(sqlCreateTable);
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
```

И должна обновляться таблица, но не обновляется:

```
    // update Table
    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO parameters (Temperature, Humidity) Values (?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(temp));
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(hum));
        conn.close();          
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if(conn != null) conn.close();                 
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Какая получается ошибка?

Comment: Вопрос решился тем, что добавила preparedStatement.execute(); в код обновления таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился тем, что добавила preparedStatement.execute(); в код обновления таблицы.